# On the definition of comoving coordinates

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, symmetry, coordinate-systems, space-expansion

In chapter 8 Carroll's *Introduction to General Relativity: Spacetime and Geometry*, he defines a set of coordinates to be 'comoving' if the metric is free of cross terms $dt\,du^i$ and the coefficient of $dt^2$ is independent of the coordinates $u^i$. The metric itself is given by: $$ds^2 = -dt^2 + R^2(t)\,\gamma_{ij}(u)\,du^idu^j,$$ where $\gamma_{ij}(u)$ is a maximally symmetric three dimensional metric.

What do the conditions for comoving coordinates physically signify?

As such, even if the coefficient of $dt^2$ depended on the coordinates, at a particular instant of time, the *space* itself is still maximally symmetric, right? Also, any observer at every instant of time at a fixed $u^i$ will remain at that coordinate, thus being comoving, even if the coefficient of $dt^2$ depended on the coordinates. What am I missing here?